# Sphinx Index doesnot work when running in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed sphinx and have done all necessary changes followed this steps
wget http://www.sphinxsearch.com/downloads/sphinx-0.9.9.tar.gz
tar -xzf sphinx-0.9.9.tar.gz

After that, we should compile Sphinx from the source:

cd sphinx-0.9.9-rc2/
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install

In Rails 3, open Gemfile in the root directory and add the line below:

gem 'thinking-sphinx', :git => 'http://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sph

And run the following command:

bundle install

Thinking Sphinx gem adds a few rake tasks to your application. The most important ones:

rake thinking_sphinx:index – Create the index
rake thinking_sphinx:reindex – Reindex Sphinx without regenerating the configuration file
rake thinking_sphinx:start – Start up Sphinx's daemon
rake thinking_sphinx:stop – Shut down the daemon

but getting error FATAL: no indexes found in config file '/home/gvo/dcms/config/development.sphinx.conf' 
but when i run same with RAILS_ENV= production it works fine. Any suggestion or help would be really great.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, those names are confusing.  You need to make sure the ThinkingSphinx configuration in `app/config/sphinx.yml` (paths, what to index) is available to the TS gem for your environment.  TS uses this config to generate the configuration used by the underlying Sphinx server.  You may have to create needed directories for the indexer to be able to write index files, logs, and a few other things.  It's likely that the config for development is different than production.

Comment: Can you please list it with an example that would be more useful.

Comment: I think you'll find a complete description of how to configure TS here http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html -- it is my understanding that stack overflow answers are intended to help the asker understand the cause of the problem.  The key to understanding is: TS has a small configuration that is consistent with Rails conventions, which, when `rake ts:index` is run, in turn generates both the configuration files as needed by Sphinx itself, and the indexes used by Sphinx.

Comment: thanks. But i followed the links still it did not worked for me ,so i posted this in stack overflow.